# Deduce template argument of outer type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Suppose I have the following template class:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Hello
{
    struct Hi {};
};
```

I want to be able to create a function like this:

```cpp
template <typename U>
void hello_hi(typename Hello<U>::Hi&)
{}
```

And use it like this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    hello_hi(Hello<int>::Hi{});
}
```

But C++ isn't able to deduce the type `U` because it is a template argument of of `Hello`, *not* `Hi`. Is there some way I can deduce `U` **without setting it explicitly** as a template argument of `hello_hi`?

Comment: As is, this is impossible. However, you could still provide a way to access the outer type's template parameter from the inner type, such as via a type alias (`struct Hi { using the_type = T; };`)